# Interesting android touch issue

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouchlistener

The problem that i am having is I am using a touch listener for the onTouch event it seems that the touch is being called more than once when i just touch it once. 
The following is my code

```
final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

        tv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            int count1 =0;
            int count2=0;
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d("Code777","Touch is being called finger");
                int i = event.getPointerCount();



                if(i==1 )
                {
                    if(count1==0)
                    {
                        Log.d("Code777","Touched with 1 finger");
                        count1++;
                        count2=0;
                    }

                }

                 if (i==2 )
                {
                     if(count2==0)
                     {
                        Log.d("Code777","Touched with 2 fingers");
                        edit.append(tv.getText());  
                        count2++;
                        count1=0;
                     }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Am i doing something wrong ??
It prints the log more than 3-4 times for both single touch and double touch

The problem updated problem is that both the events are getting fired now

```
  if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN)
                {
                    Log.d("Code777","2 finger touch");
                    return true;
                }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                        Log.d("Code777","Touched with 1 finger");


                    return true;
                }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're code will execute during every touch event.  The first time it activates, it's likely do to an `ACITON_DOWN` event (when the user first touches the screen).  The second time, it is likely do to an `ACTION_UP` event (when the user lifts the finger from the screen).  Likewise, if you were to swipe your finger around the screen, the same code will execute many times for an `ACTION_MOVE` event.  You have to check for the types of touches that it is.  Do something like this:

```
switch(event.getAction()){
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
     // Do something that should only happen when the user first touches the screen
     break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
     // Do something that should only happen when the user is touching the screen
     break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
     // Do something that should only happen when the user stops touching the screen
     break;
}
```

EDIT:

Multitouch in Android is odd at best.  Not all devices can handle it.  Not all device can handle more than x number of touches, etc.  If you want to handle DOWN cases for individual fingers, then you can use the `ACTION_POINTER_X` items.  If you were to have this series of events like so:

```
1.  User touches screen
2.  User touches screen with second finger
3.  User lifts finger 1
4.  User touches screen with finger 1
5.  User lifts finger 2
6.  User touches screen with finger 2
7.  User lifts both finger 1 and finger 2
8.  User touches screen with only finger 2
9.  User touches screen with finger 1
```

The events that will be fired will be like this:

```
1.  ACTION_DOWN
2.  ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN
3.  ACTION_POINTER_1_UP
4.  ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN
5.  ACTION_POINTER_2_UP
6.  ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN
7.  ACTION_UP (also, one of the pointers actions will fire depending on which finger was lifted first)
8.  ACTION_DOWN
9.  ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN
```

And so on.

Comment: thanks for the answer it worked as you suggested but i have another problem now , if i am using TOUCH_DOWN it is not detecting the double touch, is there any way to get around this ??

Comment: `ACTION_DOWN` is for only the first initial touch of all.  You can check for `ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN` for the second.  After which, if finger 2 is down, you life finger one, then put finger 1 back down, `ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN` will fire.

Comment: I don't understand your issue.

Comment: only double touch event is getting executed the Action_pointer_1_Down is not executed

Comment: The `ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN` event will only be executed if the *first* finger that touches the screen is lifted and put down and the second finger never stops touching the screen.  Basically think of it as an assignment.  A finger touches the screen->If pointer1 is not assigned, assign the touch to pointer1->else if pointer2 is not assigned, assign the touch to pointer2.  Multitouch in Android isn't very intuitive (though supposedly easier in Honeycomb; I don't have much experience in it).

Answer (score 1):

An `onTouchListener` sends you multiple actions via `MotionEvents`. You can get the action for the current event with `MotionEvent.getAction()`.

What you notice here is most likely that you get one `ACTION_DOWN` *(a finger has been placed on the display)* event followed by some small `ACTION_MOVE` events when you move the finger(s) slightly. In the end you will get `ACTION_UP` *(a finger has been lifted)* You can filter these out by ignoring events with the wrong action.

For example just return from onTouch() when a move event occured.

```
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d("Code777","Touch is being called finger");

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        Log.d("Code777", "Move event detected, ignored!");
        return false;
    }

    // Further processing ..
}
```

or use a switch to differentiate between all relevant events.

*See the [MotionEvent class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) for a list of possible actions.*
.

Comment: That works great. thanks
but i have another problem, if i am using TOUCH_DOWN it is not detecting the double touch, is there any way to get around this ??

Comment: You mean you don't get a ACTION_DOWN event when you place the second finger on the display?

Comment: yes, the action event is not being called.
I hope the way you test that is by getting the event.getPointerCount(); or is there some other way to detect multi touch ?

Comment: Basically that event should get fired. But it depends on the device, some have a few problems with multitouch. Which device are you using exactly?

Comment: I am using the basic droid but i dont think it is a device specific because in my previous revision of the code it was detecting the multitouch

Comment: Mhm sounds weird. That should work in theory, but I got no idea. Has been a few months since i wrote my last multitouch code, maybe something changed. I recommend to open a new question with the updated code and see if someone can spot the problem.